# How do I get rid of these briar hearts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 13 briar hearts in my inventory and I can't get rid of them because it says they're quest items.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug with the White Phial questline. Use them all up in alchemy and further Briar Hearts will not be quest items. Use one to complete Repairing the White Phial if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You can eat all of them except for I think 5, then try using the rest in Alchemy after you completed the quest the white phial